# Symfony 2 web directory rename

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony 2 project and I cant rename the web dir for some reasons. I am trying to rename it to public.

According to the manual, I am suppose to change the composer.json and make sure the links in app.php and app_dev.php is correct.

But when I run app/console server:run, it shows

```
 The given document root directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xxx/app/../web" does nto exists.
```

I have changed the composer.json, run composer install and composer update but still no luck. Here is my composer.json , as you can see I have already added "symfony-web-dir": "public" to the file.

If I rename my public folder to web, then everything is fine, but for certain reasons I can't do that.

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "richsage/rms-push-notifications-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
    "ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "public",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: did you clear your cache (as documentation says)?

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski yeah, and for some reasons I created another project just to test this and it turns out fine. Not sure why it does not work for the current one I am working on.

Comment: what is causing this error? do you have a call stack ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can indeed change the name of the 'web' directory, but the `server:run` command does not expect this. As you can see in the `ServerRunCommand` source code ([on line 77](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/62cb443770dedda65bd9edd1170f0ec0e5e4ea86/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerRunCommand.php#L77)), the 'web' directory is hard-coded in there.

However, you should be able to solve this by simply providing the `--docroot` option when running the command:

```
bin/console server:run --docroot=C:/xampp/htdocs/xxx/public
```

(replace `bin/console` with the location of the console, which may be `app/console` if you are using the Symfony 2 structure)

Comment: This worked form me in ubuntu and symfony 3:
    `php bin/console server:start --docroot=/opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/public_html`

Comment: To be honest, this is a hack on Symfony's part. Kudos for providing something that works for OP. However, the official documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html) clearly states you only have to change `extra.symfony-web-dir`, which clearly doesn't work when running the server normally (without `--docroot`). The fact `bin/console` doesn't read and respect the instructions in the composer.json file - and that people just accept this behavior - is baffling.

Comment: @Kafoso you are right that the documentation lacks some information there. I wouldn't call this a hack, though. The command offers a proper solution for overriding the web directory, it just lacks a feature that automatically reads the option from the composer.json.